# Encoding and Decoding for Student Case Class with Animal Trait

Tags: scala, circe, http4s-circe

**Problem Description**

I have a case class Student that includes instances of the Animal trait, along with two case classes Cat and Dog that extend the trait. I'm having trouble figuring out how to properly encode and decode instances of the Student class.

**Goals**
Understand how to correctly encode a Student instance to JSON.
Learn the appropriate decoding process for a JSON representation back to a Student instance.

```
import io.circe._
import io.circe.generic.semiauto._

trait Animal

case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal

case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal

case class Student(id: Int, name: String, animal: Animal)

object Student {

  implicit val catEncoder: Encoder[Cat] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val catDecoder: Decoder[Cat] = deriveDecoder
  implicit val dogEncoder: Encoder[Dog] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val dogDecoder: Decoder[Dog] = deriveDecoder

  implicit val animalEncoder: Encoder[Animal] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val animalDecoder: Decoder[Animal] = deriveDecoder

  implicit val studentEncoder: Encoder[Student] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val studentDecoder: Decoder[Student] = deriveDecoder
}

object Test extends App {

  import io.circe.syntax._

  val student = Student(1, "abc", Cat("cat"))

  val jsonString = student.asJson.noSpaces
  println("JSON representation: " + jsonString)

  val decoded: Either[io.circe.Error, Student] = io.circe.parser.decode[Student](jsonString)
  println("Decoded Student: " + decoded)
}
```

Comment: Well, you need to include some form of disambiguation in the JSON, check **circe-generic-extras** for an automatic built-in way to do that. Or, instead of deriving the `Animal` codecs, you could write one yourself with your own disambiguation logic.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Well, some disambiguation is included in `circe-generic` by default. The question is whether it's desirable. `circe-generic-extras` is for configuration. https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/adt.html

Comment: @DmytroMitin oh cool, I thought the disambiguation bit was part of `circe-generic-extras`. I stand corrected. Great answer as always BTW :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to derive a type class (codec) for a parent trait of hierarchy then the trait must be sealed

```scala
sealed trait Animal
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/td1vmuCESZePhxno7VYwUw/4

```
//JSON representation: {"id":1,"name":"abc","animal":{"Cat":{"name":"cat"}}}
//Decoded Student: Right(Student(1,abc,Cat(cat)))
```

Also on contrary to `Student`, for `Cat`, `Dog`, `Animal` the instances of type classes `Encoder`/`Decoder` are placed now out of implicit scope.

[Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits)

Implicits of types `SomeTypeclass[SomeDatatype]` should be placed to companion objects of `SomeTypeclass` or `SomeDatatype`. Then the implicits will be available without import. You can check that although `implicitly[Decoder[Student]]` compiles but for example `implicitly[Decoder[Cat]]` doesn't. So you should better write

```scala
sealed trait Animal
object Animal {
  implicit val animalEncoder: Encoder[Animal] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val animalDecoder: Decoder[Animal] = deriveDecoder
}

case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal
object Cat {
  implicit val catEncoder: Encoder[Cat] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val catDecoder: Decoder[Cat] = deriveDecoder
}

case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
object Dog {
  implicit val dogEncoder: Encoder[Dog] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val dogDecoder: Decoder[Dog] = deriveDecoder
}

case class Student(id: Int, name: String, animal: Animal)
object Student {
  implicit val studentEncoder: Encoder[Student] = deriveEncoder
  implicit val studentDecoder: Decoder[Student] = deriveDecoder
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/td1vmuCESZePhxno7VYwUw/2

Also `Encoder` + `Decoder` is just `Codec`

```scala
sealed trait Animal
object Animal {
  implicit val animalCodec: Codec[Animal] = deriveCodec
}

case class Cat(name: String) extends Animal
object Cat {
  implicit val catCodec: Codec[Cat] = deriveCodec
}

case class Dog(name: String) extends Animal
object Dog {
  implicit val dogCodec: Codec[Dog] = deriveCodec
}

case class Student(id: Int, name: String, animal: Animal)
object Student {
  implicit val studentCodec: Codec[Student] = deriveCodec
}
```

https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/td1vmuCESZePhxno7VYwUw/5